# Saved Double Values showing as 0.00 instead of what was entered in text field

Tags: swift, string, core-data, swiftui, double

I am a beginner to swift language and am trying to work on a simple expense tracking project but cannot get the Double values entered in the textfield to show in the list below when saving an item. Any help/assistance and explanation is GREATLY appreciated!

Here are is the code I'm using minus my formatter which is set to .currency

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    @State private var dollarValue: String = ""
    @State var dollarAsInt: Double = Double()
    @State private var plug: String = ""
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    // MARK: - FUNCTION
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
            newItem.dollarValue = dollarValue
            newItem.dollarAsInt = dollarAsInt
            newItem.id = UUID()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }


    
    // MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                VStack(spacing: 16){
                    TextField("Label", text: $dollarValue)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray6))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                    TextField("Dollar Amount", value: $dollarAsInt, formatter: formatter)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray6))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    
                    Button(action: {addItem()}, label: {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Save")
                        Spacer()
                    })
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                } //: VSTACK
                .padding()
                
                List {
                    
                        ForEach(items) { item in
                            HStack {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(item.dollarValue ?? "")
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    
                                    Text("\(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                        .font(.footnote)
                                }
                                Spacer()
                                VStack{
                                    Text("\(item.dollarAsInt)")
                                    //Text("\(item.dollarAsInt)")
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    
                                    Text("Category")
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                        .font(.footnote)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                }//:List
            } //: VSTACK
            .navigationBarTitle("Transactions", displayMode: .large)
            .toolbar {
                #if os(iOS)
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                #endif

                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
        } //: TOOLBAR
        } //: NAVIGATION
    }
    
    

    // MARK: - PREVIEW
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
}
```

[Preview of Error when trying to add dollar value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAY5w.png)

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Should be something I can copy and paste and run. For example you could simplify your code to just the `TextField`, the simplest example in which the problem still occurs. I can't run this example when it relies on Core Data and other types I don't have.

Comment: `var dollarAsInt: Double` is suspicious. Did you declare your 
core data item "dollarAsInt" as an Int or as a Double?

Comment: tested your code, all works well, if I declare "dollarAsInt" as a Double in core data.

Comment: So double checked and I do have dollarAsInt as a Double in core data .. but for some reason when I run it and test values in both textfields only the label is saved and passed through while the dollar value just comes across as 0.00000

Comment: I would post a minimal sample of where the error is but I honestly have no clue if its in my textfield or when I fetch it and use text("\(Double)")  to try to display the saved value or maybe in my formatter....

Comment: Have you tried entering print statements at various places or using the debugger to track what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

your code works well for me on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta,
target ios 15 and macCatalyst 12.
This is the test code I used, which should be the same as your code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

@main
struct CoreDataTestApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var dollarValue: String = ""
    @State var dollarAsInt: Double = 0.0
    @State private var plug: String = ""
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
            newItem.dollarValue = dollarValue
            newItem.dollarAsInt = dollarAsInt
            newItem.id = UUID()
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                VStack(spacing: 16){
                    TextField("Label", text: $dollarValue)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray6))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                    TextField("Dollar Amount", value: $dollarAsInt, formatter: formatter)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray6))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    
                    Button(action: {addItem()}, label: {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Save")
                        Spacer()
                    })
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                } //: VSTACK
                .padding()
                
                List {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        HStack {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(item.dollarValue ?? "")
                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                
                                Text("\(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    .font(.footnote)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            VStack{
                                Text("\(item.dollarAsInt)")
                                //Text("\(item.dollarAsInt)")
                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                
                                Text("Category")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    .font(.footnote)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                }//:List
            } //: VSTACK
            .navigationBarTitle("Transactions", displayMode: .large)
            .toolbar {
#if os(iOS)
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
#endif
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            } //: TOOLBAR
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
    
    private var formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let f = NumberFormatter()
        // allow no currency symbol, extra digits, etc
        f.isLenient = true
        f.numberStyle = .currency
        return f
    }()

    private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        formatter.timeStyle = .medium
        return formatter
    }()
    
}
```